# Checking if a user is a member of a facebook secret group

Tags: ios, facebook

I am trying to build an app that check if a user is a member of a specific facebook secret group (which I know a group ID of). I have tried to retrieve a list of members in a group to do the checking that user who login is one of member, which works well when it is in closed group and public group. However, once the group is changed to secret group, it doesn’t work anymore.
Is there any way to do such checking with a secret group? I have also tried Graph API explorer and used Facebook iOS SDK in Xcode to request data but with no success.

I got message 
"Object with ID '442xxxxxxxxxxxx' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation."

I'm not sure what permissions are missing.

Or is it impossible by Facebook design to reach such information?

Best regards.

Comment: did you try with a user token of a group admin?

Comment: Yes I tried, by created my secret group that I was admin to test and request permission "user_managed_groups" too but it not work.